# Return a value if another cell has one of many values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure if the `IF` function is even the right one to start, but the question is:
I have a cell `Y8` and it displays different numbers:

```
0,5,10,15,20,35,50
```

I need to type a formula that returns a text value, but I have 4 arguments.

I need it to return the following:
If it's...

- ...less then 10 = Level 1.
- ...between 10-19 = Level 2.
- ...20:29 = Level 3
- ...30+ = Level 4.

Using the `IF` function I only managed to get a return value of either Level 1 or Level 2 depending on the number which is constantly changing.

I have used the following formula:

```
=IF(Y8<=9, "Level 1", IF(Y8<="10:19", "Level 2"))
```

Any ideas on what formula I can use to get a return value for all 4 arguments?

Comment: I think "cases" is a better term than "argument".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this depending on how thorough you want to be.

Personally I prefer the first example:

```
=IF(Y8<=9, "Level 1", IF(Y8<=19, "Level 2", IF(Y8<=29 "Level 3", "Level 4")))
```

You don't worry about defining Level 2 as being at least 10 as it is inferred that Y8 has to be greater than 9 by not matching and returning "Level 1".

If you wanted to really thorough and define upper and lower bounds then you could do something like this, it also includes returning a warning/error in case the value in Y8 is not a number:

```
=IF(Y8<=9, "Level 1", IF(AND(Y8>=10, Y8<=19), "Level 2", IF(AND(Y8>=20, Y8<=29), "Level 3", IF(Y8>=30, "Level 4", "Not a number or some other error"))))
```

Comment: Something so simple, but I couldn't get my head round it. Thank you for your help. 1st example does the job!

Comment: @dan note that nested IFs can only get so many levels deep. This solution won't scale. `VLOOKUP` would be much simpler, and would require zero maintenance, should the thresholds ever need to change.

Comment: "Something so simple" ? @dan I think u misunderstood it.. It is NOT simple.. || It's head-scratching even for a junior programmer when they started to learn _recursively_ call a function. || In your case it is lucky coz the function involved is the basic IF(). If it is a recursive index()+match() , then I don't think it is easily explained. || Either way.. congratulation upon learning this new skill, and making an effort to make (the original) question simple and straightforwardly understandable.  ( :

Comment: The second example returned an error when I tried it. And you can have fewer nesting levels with a binary search: `=IF(Y8<20,IF(Y8<10,"Level 1", "Level 2"),IF(Y8<30,"Level 3","Level 4"))`

Comment: cheers Accumulation - added a missing comma to the second code snippet.

Answer (score 20):

You can use CHOOSE with MATCH

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(Y8,{0,10,20,30}),"Level 1","Level 2","Level 3","Level 4")
```

---

If you are really wanting the `Level` and a number we can do:

```
="Level " & MATCH(Y8,{0,10,20,30})
```

Comment: This solution scales better than the nested IFs picked by the OP.

Comment: Nice ! wish I had thought of using MATCH in my answer...

Answer (score 12):

Make a sorted lookup table with the `Level` corresponding to each threshold:

```
Value    Level
 0       1
10       2
20       3
30       4
```

Now you can use a simple `VLOOKUP` to get the `Level` given any `Value`, and if the thresholds ever need to change, or if new levels need to be added, your `VLOOKUP` formula doesn't need to change - just maintain the thresholds table, and done.

```
="Level " & VLOOKUP(theValue, theLookupTable, 2, TRUE)
```

Note the `TRUE` argument for the last parameter, making `VLOOKUP` use an *approximate match* rather than the typically-used *exact match* mode. As long as the thresholds are sorted ascending, `VLOOKUP` will return the `Level` value for the largest `Value` that is still smaller than the lookup value.

[image: Example in Excel]

Answer (score 8):

I like the answer by Scott Craner. However, I thought I would point out some other options.

If you have Excel 2016 or later, your can use the `IFS` function to simplify the structure of nested `IF` functions.

```
=IFS(Y8<10,"Level 1",Y8<20,"Level 2",Y8<30,"Level 3",TRUE,"Level 4")
```

The way it works is:

- If Y8 is less than 10, it will return "Level 1", otherwise ...
- If Y8 is less than 20, it will return "Level 2", otherwise ...
- If Y8 is less than 30, it will return "Level 3", otherwise ...
- It will return "Level 4"

In the example given in the question, the "level" number increases by one each time the value in Y8 increases by 10. In this special case, it is possible to calculate the level number without using `IF`.

```
="Level "&INT(MIN(30,MAX(0,Y8))/10)+1
```

Note that the question states that any value less than 10 is level 1 and any value greater than 30 is level 4. In order to force negative numbers to be "Level 1" and numbers greater than 39 to be level 4, the formula uses `MIN(30,MAX(0,Y8))` instead of `Y8`.

Comment: my personal favorite answer.. nailed it.. nice shoot. || for @dan .. this is a mathematically induced dose on excel formula.. inputOutput pattern matching method.. best the best an algo can get.  ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ Agree on the soundness of the math-based approach, but disagree that it's the best way to go: it makes an assumption on the data and encodes it into terse math logic. If the assumptions are ever invalidated (e.g. 6 months later, need a level 5 for 50+), then everything needs to be rewritten. Upvoted for `IFS`, but the math-based approach isn't respecting the original specifications for the upper bound value (i.e. return 4 for 30+), and making it so would involve further complicating the formula, making it encode even more metadata rather than simply reading like the specs.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I thoroughly agree that the maths-based approach is not the best one for the general case, the OP would have to consider how set in stone the "10 values per level" pattern is. Thanks for pointing out that I didn't correctly handle the >30 case. I'll correct that (although, as you say, it will make the formula more complicated).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the heads up.. in general case, I'd agree with you. ( :  || "the best" statement only goes for me I guess.. with my favorite theme of doing things... may not be the best for others.. || IMHO, if this was a competition, this solution will easily lose.. but , it worth an honorable mention.

Comment: @p._phidot_ eh, I'm severely biased towards separating logic and data (programmer background, I guess); logic is usually dead-simple, it's the changing data/metadata that complicates things - IMO that's the case here; inlining the array (as in the top-voted answer) works for small sets, but won't scale nicely to e.g. 100 items ...which may or may not be a concern or even a possibility. Full separation of the data (as in mine) can be overkill, but seldom fails to scale and makes maintenance simpler, again just IMO =)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to create a table holding the lower bounds of your values and using VLOOKUP

[table with level values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZVjC.png)

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup value, table array, col_index_num,[range lookup])
```

The last variable in VLOOKUP is "Approximate match" TRUE/FALSE

Choosing the former will have the function attempt to find the "nearest value" with numbers this results in the function looking for any value "lower" than the input in the table. Using 9 as an example the closest result is 0 and will return "level 1".

this method also allows you to increase your options and levels on the fly.

Comment: That's... the answer I posted 15 minutes ago.

Comment: Yeah I was otherwise occupied while typing this. Will upvote yours though.

Comment: Yay team-vlookup!

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It isn't uncommon for someone to post a nearly identical solution while you're is working on their own.  The intention is that each answer should provide a solution that hasn't already been contributed.  In that situation, unless your answer adds something substantive, consider deleting it.  It happens to everyone.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using nested `IFs`, you can use `CHOOSE`:

```
=IF(Y8>30,"Level 4",CHOOSE(MAX(1,ROUNDUP((Y8-1)/10,0)),"Level 1","Level 2","Level 3"))
```

Where there are only 4 different conditions I would usually use a series of nested `IFs`, but if you had say 100 conditions, it is a lot easier to use `CHOOSE`.

Comment: That doesn't work at all. Did you try any test values?

Comment: Re try it, misplaced the bracket around the minus 1